# NSFileManager filePathNotReadable

Tags: swift, nsfilemanager

I'm developing a simple app that stores some pictures on the Documents directory and it works fine, but if I restart the app I don't have the privileges to read the files.

This code print "can't read" only when he have to read an older image.

```
let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
if !fileManager.isReadableFileAtPath(photo.imagePath) {
    println("can't read")
}
let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: photo.imagePath))
var image : UIImage = UIImage(data: data)
```

All the images are saved with this code:

```
func savePNGImage(image: UIImage, imageName: String) -> (String){
    let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, NSSearchPathDomainMask.UserDomainMask, true)
    let documentsDirectory :String = paths[0] as String
    let path = documentsDirectory.stringByAppendingPathComponent("\(imageName).png")
    let data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)
    data.writeToFile(path, atomically: true)
    println("Saved in: \(path)")

    return path
}
```

Another example, the executions of this code:

```
let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
let exists = NSFileManager.defaultManager().fileExistsAtPath(photo.imagePath)
println("-")
println("Current path: \(photo.imagePath)")
let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory,NSSearchPathDomainMask.UserDomainMask, true)
let documentsDirectory :String = paths[0] as String
println("Contents of Documents dir: \(fileManager.contentsOfDirectoryAtPath(documentsDirectory, error: nil))")
println("Exists? \(exists)")
if !fileManager.isReadableFileAtPath(photo.imagePath) {
    println("can't read")
}
println(photo.imageName)
println(photo.text)
println(photo.imagePath)
```

Print this:

> Current path: /Users/giacomomanzoli/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/DB2556F4-69C5-4051-97AB-5F46C32D8C1E/data/Containers/Data/Application/4FF0A409-F0AA-4FDB-AF69-8D33576D9470/Documents/sdasdasdasd.png
>       Contents of Documents dir: Optional([SampleCoreData.sqlite, SampleCoreData.sqlite-shm, SampleCoreData.sqlite-wal, sdasdasdasd.m4a, sdasdasdasd.png, test.m4a, test.png, test2.m4a, test2.png])
>       Exists? false
>       can't read
>       sdasdasdasd
>       sdasdasdasd
>       /Users/giacomomanzoli/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/DB2556F4-69C5-4051-97AB-5F46C32D8C1E/data/Containers/Data/Application/4FF0A409-F0AA-4FDB-AF69-8D33576D9470/Documents/sdasdasdasd.png
>       -
>       Current path: /Users/giacomomanzoli/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/DB2556F4-69C5-4051-97AB-5F46C32D8C1E/data/Containers/Data/Application/01DA29C8-F3A8-452F-AEC9-43DAE354607D/Documents/test.png
>       Contents of Documents dir: Optional([SampleCoreData.sqlite, SampleCoreData.sqlite-shm, SampleCoreData.sqlite-wal, sdasdasdasd.m4a, sdasdasdasd.png, test.m4a, test.png, test2.m4a, test2.png])
>       Exists? false
>       can't read
>       test
>       test
>       /Users/giacomomanzoli/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/DB2556F4-69C5-4051-97AB-5F46C32D8C1E/data/Containers/Data/Application/01DA29C8-F3A8-452F-AEC9-43DAE354607D/Documents/test.png
>       -
>       Current path: /Users/giacomomanzoli/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/DB2556F4-69C5-4051-97AB-5F46C32D8C1E/data/Containers/Data/Application/6F720075-27FC-4211-8521-CBB05E1CE523/Documents/test2.png
>       Contents of Documents dir: Optional([SampleCoreData.sqlite, SampleCoreData.sqlite-shm, SampleCoreData.sqlite-wal, sdasdasdasd.m4a, sdasdasdasd.png, test.m4a, test.png, test2.m4a, test2.png])
>       Exists? false
>       can't read
>       test2
>       test2
>       /Users/giacomomanzoli/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/DB2556F4-69C5-4051-97AB-5F46C32D8C1E/data/Containers/Data/Application/6F720075-27FC-4211-8521-CBB05E1CE523/Documents/test2.png

I also tried to save the picture with `NSFileManager.defaultManager().createFileAtPath(path, contents: data, attributes: nil)` but the situation didn't change.
Could it be a bug of the simulator?

Comment: Does this work on the simulator? Have you verified that a) the paths are the same between saving and reading and b) if the file is actually at the path you are saving to?

Comment: It works on the simulator just the first time, but when i restart the app all the pictures are gone.
The path are the same and right.

Comment: In the Finder, go to the path and see if the images are there.

Comment: Already tried, pictures exists. It seems that the file manager has no right to open the files that already exist

Comment: If your app wrote it, then it should be able to read it. Something else is happening. What is returned if you say let exists = NSFileManager.defaultManager().fileExistsAtPath(photo.imagePath)

Comment: Result on pastebin: http://pastebin.com/zhWnPXpC (too many characters)

Comment: Absolute path is changing on every launch, so you have to save the data on relative path and retrieve it on appending absolute path and relative path every time. In your case don't save Absolute path in `photo.imagePath` instead of this save name of image only.